# Plotting POSIXct in ggplot manually scaling x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, posixct

I am trying to plot up this windspeed data, with years displaying on the x-axis. The data frame was set up as

```
wsAvg<-data.frame(date=as.POSIXct(ws07$date[1224:1559]),u.1=(ws07$u[1224:1559]),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
wsAvg<-rbind(wsAvg,c(date=as.POSIXct(ws08$date[1032:1367]),(ws08$u[1032:1367])))
```

And below using ggplot to plot my windspeed data frame.

```
ggplot(wsAvg,aes(x=date,y=as.numeric(u.1)))+geom_point(size=3,pch=2)+
  geom_smooth(method="lm",colour="black",se=FALSE)+
  #scale_x_datetime(limits=as.POSIXct(c('2006-09-01','2016-10-01')),breaks=date_breaks("1 year"),labels=date_format("%Y"))+
```

[image]

Without the `scale_x_datetime()` in my command, I get those dates. When I add in the `scale_x_datetime()` function to manually scale my x-axis to display only years. All my data lines up onto 2007. Anyone know why this is?
[image]

Comment: Looks correct for me, we do not have you data, but your first plot shows just two month, and your second plot many years. I think the functions are working correctly. What do you expect?

Comment: @J_F For simplicity, I did not paste the entire data set. Both plots have the same amount of years of data 2006-2016. The axis label on the first plot is from the default of ggplot and is not what I am looking for

Comment: Can you give us a example of your dataset, e.g. one point per year?

Comment: @J_F Each data consists of 14 points at different time stamps of the year. So I have 8 more lines of code following the first two lines of creating the wsAvg data frame, each similar to the second line `rbind()` of 2009 all the way to 2016.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, that includes enough example data to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to provide the answer to your question, since we don't have a clear picture of any of your data.  With that being said, let's look at the information you did provide and see where the likely source of the problem is for your question.

The issue is clearly related to the formatting/data located in your "date" column.  It's best to look at this stepwise and test at each step to see what can go wrong here:

- **Your raw data:**  There is likely nothing *wrong* with your base data, but we don't know the format of the "date" vector coming from `ws07$date[1224:1559]` and `ws08$date[1032:1367]`.  Your raw data originates from two data frames, so just confirm that the raw data from these two vectors is formatted identically, but more importantly, is it *already formatted as a date?*  What is `class(ws08$date)`?  Also, what does the data look like if you took a sample of that dataset?  (e.g. `ws07$date[sample(1224:1559, 20)]`).
- **Conversion to POSIXct:** The first code you show includes `as.POSIXct()`, but *does not* include the argument for `format=`.  You may or may not need to specify this, but I would recommend [consulting the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.POSIX*) to be sure you're using the function correctly.  You can try converting a small subset of the data just using `as.POSIXct(ws07$date[1224:1250])` or something like that.  Does it give you the dates formatted correctly?  If not, try specifying the `format=` arg until it "works" as you intended.
- **Initial Plot and Second plot**  The data is spread out in the first plot, likely kind of how you expected.  What about the month/day combinations in the first plot - are they correct?  If they are correct, it may indicate the year is being read wrong, since apparently all dates are clustered around May and June of 2007.  Comparing the first and second plots, there's no obvious issue with `scale_x_datetime()` here.  Those two plots are consistent with data that has x values = dates ranging from May-June of 2007.

Bottom line: Hard to discern exactly where it's going wrong for you, but likely it's (1) in the conversion to date using `as.POSIXct` from your `ws07` and `ws08` datasets, or (2) the format of `ws07$date` or `ws08$date` being imported/converted incorrectly.  The solution is to use the `format=` argument in the date conversion/import function you are using to ensure that the format is correct and years/months/dates are imported accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your in depth analysis. I managed to find out what went wrong. When I was setting up my data frame, instead of using the c() function, I had to use data.frame() for it to accept the data. I'm not sure the logic or the reason why c() doesn't work and data.frame() does.

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch that when I first saw your problem.  Yes, when you create the data you are binding a dataframe with a vector that is actually a dataframe, so 'c()' doesn't work there.

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked for me. Instead of using c() function when I was binding data from other datasets, I had to use data.frame() to add other years into the wsAvg data frame.

```
wsAvg<-data.frame(date=as.POSIXct(ws07$date[1224:1559]),u.1=(ws07$u[1224:1559]),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
wsAvg<-rbind(wsAvg,data.frame(date=as.POSIXct(ws08$date[1032:1367]),u.1=(ws08$u[1032:1367])))
```